# Stop jquery action if another is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page containing two pages that appears with certain action in panel, first one is view as the user log in to the website,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
            $.get("activePages.xhtml", function(data) {
                $(".parent-panel").append(data);
            });});
```

the main page contains a button that on click it clears the panel and append the second page

```
$('.main-button2').click(function(e) {
                $(".parent-panel").empty();
                $.get("history.xhtml", function(data) {
                    $(".parent-panel").append(data);
                });
            });
```

my problem is that the first page may take too much time to be loaded then appended so if I click the button without giving time to the first page load, the first page and the second will be both appended under each other, how to stop this?

Comment: Try using .promise().done()

Comment: Disable button on start of first script and enable it again after completion

Comment: So you need to wait for the first page to fully load? using promise.done() on the first append should achieve this or disable the button as @BhushanKawadkar said

Comment: Thank you all I will try this , so promise.done() first then disable the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is binding click event when you need it. Like below I bound the click event only after the page is appended.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.get("activePages.xhtml", function(data) {
        $(".parent-panel").append(data);
        $('.main-button2').click(function(e) {
           $(".parent-panel").empty();
           $.get("history.xhtml", function(data) {
               $(".parent-panel").append(data);
           });
        });
    });
});
```